# How to re-use type in React & TS application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making application in React & TS and trying to do my best to improve code (re-use type).

I have type:

```js
export type Book = {
    author: string
    title: string
}
```

Now I have 2 components which I am using this type.

In the first component, my compiler does not see any problems. (books.data - array of object with `type Book`)

```js
<BookContent>
  {books.data.map((book: Book) => {
    return <SingleBook key={book.id} book={book} />;
  })}
</BookContent>;
```

But in SingleBook component I am getting error type in props: `Property 'book' does not exist on type 'Book'.ts(2339)`

```js
export const SingleBook = ({ book }: Book) => {
  return <SingleBookContainer>...restOfCode</SingleBookContainer>;
};
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

EDIT:

```
(property) book: Book
Type '{ key: number; book: Book; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Book'.
  Property 'book' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Book'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: change `{ book }: Book` to `book: Book`

Comment: Now, in First component, when I hover book ={book} I am getting following error. I edited question @TobiasS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are destructuring props and type it as Book

1st solution

```js
export const SingleBook = ({ book }: { book: Book }) => {
  return <SingleBookContainer>...restOfCode</SingleBookContainer>;
};
```

2nd solution

```js
type Props = {
  book: Book
}

export const SingleBook = ({ book }: Props) => {
  return <SingleBookContainer>...restOfCode</SingleBookContainer>;
};
```